# docker compose with Symfony Sylius project on windows 11

Tags: docker, symfony, sylius

*I want to try a Symfony sylius project and I'm in Windows 11 host OS.*

*My composer install run perfectly.*

*My yarn install run perfectly.*

But when I run `docker compose` into origin source code sylius (preconfigured docker) project I throw this error :

```
  => CACHED [myproject-php sylius_php_prod 11/21] RUN set -eux;     composer install --prefer-dist --no-autoloader   0.0s 
 => CACHED [myproject-php sylius_php_prod 12/21] COPY .env .env.prod .env.test .env.test_cached ./                  0.0s 
 => CACHED [myproject-php sylius_php_prod 13/21] COPY bin bin/                                                      0.0s 
 => [myproject-php sylius_php_prod 14/21] COPY config config/                                                       0.1s 
 => [myproject-php sylius_php_prod 15/21] COPY public public/                                                       0.1s 
 => [myproject-php sylius_php_prod 16/21] COPY src src/                                                             0.1s 
 => [myproject-php sylius_php_prod 17/21] COPY templates templates/                                                 0.1s 
 => [myproject-php sylius_php_prod 18/21] COPY translations translations/                                           0.1s 
 => ERROR [myproject-php sylius_php_prod 19/21] RUN set -eux;     mkdir -p var/cache var/log;     composer dump-a  12.7s 
------
 > [myproject-php sylius_php_prod 19/21] RUN set -eux;     mkdir -p var/cache var/log;     composer dump-autoload --class
                                                                                                                       smap-authoritative;     APP_SECRET='' composer run-script post-install-cmd;     chmod +x bin/console; sync;     bin/conso
                                                                                                                       ole sylius:install:assets --no-interaction;     bin/console sylius:theme:assets:install public --no-interaction:
#0 0.238 + mkdir -p var/cache var/log
#0 0.238 + composer dump-autoload --classmap-authoritative
#0 0.423 Generating optimized autoload files (authoritative)
#0 3.436 Class Payum\Be2Bill\Tests\Be2billOffsiteGatewayFactoryTest located in ./vendor/payum/payum/src/Payum/Be2Bill/Te
                                                                                                                       ests/Be2BillOffsiteGatewayFactoryTest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
#0 3.517 Generated optimized autoload files (authoritative) containing 11434 classes
#0 3.528 + APP_SECRET= composer run-script post-install-cmd
#0 3.732
#0 3.732 Run composer recipes at any time to see the status of your Symfony recipes.
#0 3.732
#0 3.750 Executing script cache:clear [OK]
#0 12.10 Executing script assets:install public
#0 12.53  [OK]
#0 12.53 + chmod +x bin/console
#0 12.58 + sync
#0 12.64 + bin/console sylius:install:assets --no-interaction
': No such file or directory'php
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c set -eux;     mkdir -p var/cache var/log;     composer dump-autoloa
                                                                                                                       ad --classmap-authoritative;     APP_SECRET='' composer run-script post-install-cmd;     chmod +x bin/console; sync;     
                                                                                                                        bin/console sylius:install:assets --no-interaction;     bin/console sylius:theme:assets:install public --no-interaction]
                                                                                                                       ]: exit code: 127
`docker-compose` process finished with exit code 17
```

Docker can correctly created var/cache and var/log directory into OS host

But docker not starting my container

Why docker tell me about PHP directory ?

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to the `bin/console` file having the wrong line endings.
If you have [git autocrlf](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_core_autocrlf) configured, then git replaced LF with CRLF in all project files.
You can add a step to the Dockerfile to change it back to LH using `dos2unix`.
You can also change them to LF on Windows, but then you can't execute it on Windows.
To force it to LF regardless of the `autocrlf` value you can add `bin/console text eol=lf` to `.gitattributes` file from the project root dir.